# entityType can get and save data

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, symfony-forms, symfony6

I've 4 entities Company, Network, Customer and Process.

I don't know why I use fucntion create and edit don't save process in my DB !

Cutomers Netwoks and Compny this saved well.

Perhaps I forget somethings.

Some one can help please.

Company Form `

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Entity\Process;
use App\Form\NetworkType;
use App\Form\CustomerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'required' => 'true',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1',
                ],
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Ce champ ne peut-être vide'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('phone', TelType::class, [
                'required' => 'true',
                'label' => 'Téléphone',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1',
                    'placeholder' => 'xx xx xx xx xx'
                ],
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Ce champ ne peut-être vide'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('location', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Ville',
                'required' => 'true',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1'
                ],
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'mt-1'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Ce champ ne peut-être vide'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('customers', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CustomerType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('networks', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => NetworkType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('processes', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Process::class,
                // 'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                // 'allow_add' => true,
                // 'allow_delete' => true,
                // 'by_reference' => false,
                'choice_label' => 'software',
                'label' => 'process',
                'multiple' => true,
                // 'expanded' => true
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Company::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

`Company View`

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    {{company.name}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light navbar-light sticky-top px-4 py-0">
        {% include "navigation/_nav-horizontal.html.twig" %}
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Process</h5>
                        {% for process in company.processes %}
                            {# {% for key in process.software %} #}
                                <p class="card-text">{{process.software}}</p>
                            {# {% endfor %} #}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Architecture réseau</h5>
                        {% for network in company.networks %}
                            <h6>{{network.title}}</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">{{network.content}}</p>
                            {% if network.attachment %}
                                <p class="card-text">{{network.attachment}}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Contacts</h5>
                        {% for customer in company.customers %}
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#{{customer.firstname}}">
                                {{customer.firstname}}
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="{{customer.firstname}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">{{customer.firstname}}</h1>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="my-3">{{customer.firstname}}</div>
                                            <div class="my-3">{{customer.lastname}}</div>
                                            <div class="my-3">{{customer.mobile}}</div>
                                            <div class="my-3">{{customer.email}}</div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Modifier</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% include "partiel/_footer.html.twig" %}
{% endblock %}
```

`Company Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Form\CompanyType;
use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class CompanyController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/company', name: 'company', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(CompanyRepository $repo, PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        $companies = $repo->findAll();
        $companies = $paginator->paginate(
            $companies, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1), /*page number*/
            15 /*limit per page*/
        );
        return $this->render('company/index.html.twig', [
            'companies' => $companies,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/company/add', name: 'company_add', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    #[Route('/company/edit/{slug}', name: 'company_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function addOrEdit(Company $company = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        
        $message = 'Société modifié avec succès';
        $messageType = 'info';
        if (is_null($company)) {
            $company = new Company();
            $message = 'Société ajouté avec succès';
            $messageType = 'success';
        }
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        // dd($form);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // dd($form);
            // Ajout de Contacts
            foreach ($company->getCustomers() as $customer) {
                $customer->setIsActive(true);
            }
            $company->setIsActive(true);
            // dd($company);
            $em->persist($company->setUser($user));
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash($messageType, $message);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('company');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('company/add_or_edit.html.twig', [
            'company' => $company,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/company/{slug}', name: 'company_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(Company $company): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        if (!$company) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('La société est introuvable');
        }
// dd($company);
        return $this->render('company/show.html.twig', [
            'company' => $company,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/company/status/{slug}', name: 'company_status', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function status(Company $company, ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        if (!$company) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('La société est introuvable');
        }
        $oldStatus = $company->getIsActive();
        if ($oldStatus === true) {
            $newStatus = false;
        } else {
            $newStatus = true;
        }
        $company->setIsActive($newStatus);

        $em = $doctrine->getManager();
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('company');
    }
}
```

`

Thank's indeed

I try to get a add or edit Company but I can't get and save processes

Comment: `$em->persist($company->setUser($user))`

Did you return `$this` from `setUser` method.  If not please do

Comment: Thank's for reply, Yes I did it but I don't think this the problem because I've a Company form with 3 forms embedded 2 in CollectionType and one in EntityType.
When I use edit or add function I see all data but after persist and flush I see for two entities (CollectionType) save data in DB but not for EntityType !

Comment: You need to set `'by_reference' => false` on the `processes` field in your `CompanyType`. This forces the form to use the `addProcess` method when adding `Process` objects to your `Company`. `addProcess` sets the correct `Company` onto each `Process` which is needed for them to be saved correctly.

Comment: @Marleen U right, Thank's thank's indeed .
Thank U for Ure explanation, now all it's ok